# loop and split to display by 2 rows or divs

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

Currently  , What I did something like this :

```
<?php 
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
echo "<div>";
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
    echo $i;
}
echo "</div>";

echo "<div>";
for($i=4;$i<=6;$i++){
    echo $i;
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

How can I use one loop and produce the same output (display 2 rows with 3 cols)?

Comment: Do you need that for this spesific array or for a pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `array_chunk()`. Example:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$a = array_chunk($a, 3);
echo '<div>';
foreach($a as $v){
    echo $v[0] . $v[1] . $v[2];
    echo '<br />';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    echo "<div>";
    for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
        if ($i == 4) {
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div>";
        }
        echo $i;
    }
    echo "</div>";
?>
```